# "Base classes have conflicting values for attribute" when using a Python mixin to overide a base class method

Tags: python, django, inheritance, mixins

I have a django mixin:

```
class PublicSchemaOnlyAdminAccessMixin:
    def has_view_or_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return connection.schema_name == get_public_schema_name()

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return connection.schema_name == get_public_schema_name()

    def has_module_permission(self, request):
        return connection.schema_name == get_public_schema_name()
```

That is used in many of my ModelAdmin classes, for example:

```
class BlockAdmin(PublicSchemaOnlyAdminAccessMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

But I'm getting warning about this structure from LGTM:

> Base classes have conflicting values for attribute 'has_add_permission': Function has_add_permission and Function has_add_permission.

However, none of their [proposed solutions](https://lgtm.com/rules/7860084/) seem to be practical for this, since I am using this in about half of my Admin classes.

Is there either A. A better way for me to resolve this bad code structure or B. Is this code structure fine (as long as I understand the classes are read from right to left and the mixin must go on the left for consistant behaviour)

Comment: As long as you understand the warning and how your code will effectively behave, this is perfectly ok (and a rather common case FWIW).

Comment: NB: I'm voting to close this as opinion-based, not because your question is wrong in itself but because asserting that this "makes the code harder to understand and maintain" is really a matter of opinion. Everything else mentionned in the page you linked to is just ordinary Python behaviour and is only an "issue" if you don't understand multiple inheritance and the mro (IOW it's not a TECHNICAL issue).